# Screen keeps freezing, then kernel panic

Tags: 11.04, ati, graphics, radeon, kernel

I have a Hp DV6-3079tx.

It has a ATI Radeon graphics chip.

The system seems to randomly freeze up, sometimes it will unfreeze, other times it will un-freeze, freeze, then go black.

Looking in [the full log](http://pastebin.com/vkbFwqT8) with this exerpt.

```
Jul  3 16:15:23 hailwood-ubu kernel: [ 4211.907266] ------------[ cut here ]------------
Jul  3 16:15:23 hailwood-ubu kernel: [ 4211.907303] WARNING: at /build/buildd/linux-2.6.38/drivers/gpu/drm/radeon/radeon_fence.c:248 radeon_fence_wait+0x36f/0x3e0 [radeon]()
Jul  3 16:15:23 hailwood-ubu kernel: [ 4211.907309] Hardware name: HP Pavilion dv6 Notebook PC
Jul  3 16:15:23 hailwood-ubu kernel: [ 4211.907314] GPU lockup (waiting for 0x0005418F last fence id 0x00054188)
Jul  3 16:15:23 hailwood-ubu kernel: [ 4211.907318] Modules linked in: usb_storage uas cryptd aes_x86_64 aes_generic binfmt_misc parport_pc ppdev snd_hda_codec_hdmi snd_hda_codec_idt snd_hda_intel snd_hda_codec snd_hwdep snd_seq_midi arc4 snd_pcm snd_rawmidi ath9k snd_seq_midi_event snd_seq snd_timer radeon snd_seq_device hp_wmi ttm mac80211 sparse_keymap uvcvideo ath9k_common ath9k_hw i7core_edac ath psmouse snd edac_core videodev joydev v4l2_compat_ioctl32 cfg80211 serio_raw drm_kms_helper drm soundcore snd_page_alloc i2c_algo_bit hp_accel lis3lv02d video input_polldev lp parport usbhid hid ahci r8169 libahci
Jul  3 16:15:23 hailwood-ubu kernel: [ 4211.907393] Pid: 1592, comm: gnome-shell Not tainted 2.6.38-8-generic #42-Ubuntu
Jul  3 16:15:23 hailwood-ubu kernel: [ 4211.907398] Call Trace:
Jul  3 16:15:23 hailwood-ubu kernel: [ 4211.907409]  [<ffffffff81065cef>] ? warn_slowpath_common+0x7f/0xc0
Jul  3 16:15:23 hailwood-ubu kernel: [ 4211.907417]  [<ffffffff81065de6>] ? warn_slowpath_fmt+0x46/0x50
Jul  3 16:15:23 hailwood-ubu kernel: [ 4211.907447]  [<ffffffffa03076df>] ? radeon_fence_wait+0x36f/0x3e0 [radeon]
Jul  3 16:15:23 hailwood-ubu kernel: [ 4211.907456]  [<ffffffff81087f30>] ? autoremove_wake_function+0x0/0x40
Jul  3 16:15:23 hailwood-ubu kernel: [ 4211.907486]  [<ffffffffa0307fc1>] ? radeon_sync_obj_wait+0x11/0x20 [radeon]
Jul  3 16:15:23 hailwood-ubu kernel: [ 4211.907499]  [<ffffffffa01cdb0d>] ? ttm_bo_wait+0xfd/0x1b0 [ttm]
Jul  3 16:15:23 hailwood-ubu kernel: [ 4211.907512]  [<ffffffffa01d07e6>] ? ttm_bo_move_accel_cleanup+0x1c6/0x260 [ttm]
Jul  3 16:15:23 hailwood-ubu kernel: [ 4211.907542]  [<ffffffffa030827f>] ? radeon_move_blit.clone.0+0x11f/0x180 [radeon]
Jul  3 16:15:23 hailwood-ubu kernel: [ 4211.907572]  [<ffffffffa0308595>] ? radeon_move_ram_vram.clone.2+0x125/0x150 [radeon]
Jul  3 16:15:23 hailwood-ubu kernel: [ 4211.907580]  [<ffffffff81124507>] ? vma_prio_tree_next+0x47/0x70
Jul  3 16:15:23 hailwood-ubu kernel: [ 4211.907592]  [<ffffffffa01d33db>] ? ttm_eu_list_ref_sub+0x3b/0x60 [ttm]
Jul  3 16:15:23 hailwood-ubu kernel: [ 4211.907622]  [<ffffffffa03087a8>] ? radeon_bo_move+0x1e8/0x1f0 [radeon]
Jul  3 16:15:23 hailwood-ubu kernel: [ 4211.907635]  [<ffffffffa01ce89e>] ? ttm_bo_handle_move_mem+0x12e/0x3d0 [ttm]
Jul  3 16:15:23 hailwood-ubu kernel: [ 4211.907647]  [<ffffffffa01cf982>] ? ttm_bo_move_buffer+0x142/0x160 [ttm]
Jul  3 16:15:23 hailwood-ubu kernel: [ 4211.907659]  [<ffffffffa01d33db>] ? ttm_eu_list_ref_sub+0x3b/0x60 [ttm]
Jul  3 16:15:23 hailwood-ubu kernel: [ 4211.907671]  [<ffffffffa01cfa36>] ? ttm_bo_validate+0x96/0x120 [ttm]
Jul  3 16:15:23 hailwood-ubu kernel: [ 4211.907700]  [<ffffffffa030974c>] ? radeon_bo_list_validate+0x7c/0xe0 [radeon]
Jul  3 16:15:23 hailwood-ubu kernel: [ 4211.907735]  [<ffffffffa03225d6>] ? radeon_cs_parser_relocs+0x236/0x270 [radeon]
Jul  3 16:15:23 hailwood-ubu kernel: [ 4211.907770]  [<ffffffffa0322a61>] ? radeon_cs_ioctl+0xa1/0x1e0 [radeon]
Jul  3 16:15:23 hailwood-ubu kernel: [ 4211.907778]  [<ffffffff81134b53>] ? vma_link+0xc3/0x100
Jul  3 16:15:23 hailwood-ubu kernel: [ 4211.907795]  [<ffffffffa00b3384>] ? drm_ioctl+0x3e4/0x4c0 [drm]
Jul  3 16:15:23 hailwood-ubu kernel: [ 4211.907830]  [<ffffffffa03229c0>] ? radeon_cs_ioctl+0x0/0x1e0 [radeon]
Jul  3 16:15:23 hailwood-ubu kernel: [ 4211.907840]  [<ffffffff8117648f>] ? do_vfs_ioctl+0x8f/0x360
Jul  3 16:15:23 hailwood-ubu kernel: [ 4211.907847]  [<ffffffff811767f1>] ? sys_ioctl+0x91/0xa0
Jul  3 16:15:23 hailwood-ubu kernel: [ 4211.907855]  [<ffffffff8100c002>] ? system_call_fastpath+0x16/0x1b
Jul  3 16:15:23 hailwood-ubu kernel: [ 4211.907860] ---[ end trace ff6b61aa2bd9f6b5 ]---
Jul  3 16:15:23 hailwood-ubu kernel: [ 4211.909135] radeon 0000:01:00.0: GPU softreset 
Jul  3 16:15:23 hailwood-ubu kernel: [ 4211.909140] radeon 0000:01:00.0:   GRBM_STATUS=0xF5702828
Jul  3 16:15:23 hailwood-ubu kernel: [ 4211.909145] radeon 0000:01:00.0:   GRBM_STATUS_SE0=0xFC000005
Jul  3 16:15:23 hailwood-ubu kernel: [ 4211.909151] radeon 0000:01:00.0:   GRBM_STATUS_SE1=0x00000007
Jul  3 16:15:23 hailwood-ubu kernel: [ 4211.909156] radeon 0000:01:00.0:   SRBM_STATUS=0x20000AC0
Jul  3 16:15:23 hailwood-ubu kernel: [ 4211.909187] radeon 0000:01:00.0:   GRBM_SOFT_RESET=0x00007F6B
Jul  3 16:15:23 hailwood-ubu kernel: [ 4211.909294] radeon 0000:01:00.0:   GRBM_STATUS=0x00003828
Jul  3 16:15:23 hailwood-ubu kernel: [ 4211.909299] radeon 0000:01:00.0:   GRBM_STATUS_SE0=0x00000007
Jul  3 16:15:23 hailwood-ubu kernel: [ 4211.909304] radeon 0000:01:00.0:   GRBM_STATUS_SE1=0x00000007
Jul  3 16:15:23 hailwood-ubu kernel: [ 4211.909309] radeon 0000:01:00.0:   SRBM_STATUS=0x200000C0
Jul  3 16:15:23 hailwood-ubu kernel: [ 4211.910317] radeon 0000:01:00.0: GPU reset succeed
Jul  3 16:15:23 hailwood-ubu kernel: [ 4211.951371] radeon 0000:01:00.0: WB enabled
Jul  3 16:15:23 hailwood-ubu kernel: [ 4211.968136] [drm] ring test succeeded in 2 usecs
Jul  3 16:15:23 hailwood-ubu kernel: [ 4211.968153] [drm] ib test succeeded in 3 usecs
Jul  3 16:15:34 hailwood-ubu kernel: [ 4223.287726] radeon 0000:01:00.0: GPU lockup CP stall for more than 10020msec
```

It looks like my graphics chip is having some issues.

Can anyone tell me what is happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reboot using a LiveCD and choose the option Memory Check, also check the GPU temperature when running intensive work.

Comment: How can I check the temp?

Answer (score 0):

You can try a different version of Ubuntu...
What version of Ubuntu are you running?

I have one graphics card that's decently old, and apparently the only set of good drivers work in Ubuntu 8.04 or some ridiculously old version like that.  Admittedly I haven't dug into the problem to see if there is a fix to make them work with the current version, but at the moment I'm running the most recent Ubuntu with inferior graphics because I'm using the default drivers for it.

Also, don't forget the memory check and GPU temperature, as suggested by juancarlospaco.  This could indicate hardware failure/malfunction.

Comment: 11.04 (as tagged ;) ), and it's a brand new laptop, so I don't think I need old drivers. cheers though.